# pass outer loop variable into nested loop

Tags: batch-file

So my mission is to loop through a directory and set a variable to capture the zip file name.
then use that variable to parse what is on the left of the string before the underscore. That way I can name a log file. I searched high and low but I'm not seeing any good examples on Stack. when I use `%%i` it will return a full directory path. (which is not needed here.) If I use the `%%z` I get null back how can I pass my `%zipfile%` variable into my nested loop `In()`?

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set dir1="C:\test\"

set 7zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

set output="C:\test\Filelist.txt"


REM enter folder location

cd  C:\test


REM loop through zip files

    for /r %%i in (*.zip) do ( set zipfile=%%~nxi
                           
                                for /F " delims=_" %%z in (%zipfile%) do (set  log="%%z_file_list.txt")
                          
    )
    Pause
    
    REM Del %log%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following help you out?

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "dir1=C:\test"
Set "7zip="%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Set "output=C:\test\Filelist.txt"

For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    'Set "PATHEXT=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /F /R "%dir1%" "?*_*.zip" 2^>NUL'
) Do (
    For /F "Delims=_" %%H In (
        "%%~nG"
    ) Do (
        Echo Set "log=%%H_file_list.txt"
    )
)
Pause
```

Comment: yes, Thank you so much. now I can finish this batch file. I'll post my completed process in a new post, For all users to get around deleting files that are over a certain size or under a certain size. without unzipping the archive.

Comment: Just be aware @Tdubs, that if you are wanting to do that, i.e. provide a self answer, please make sure that your question is a fully defined a reproducible problem, and that your code answers that problem. I must assume that you are extracting the zip files, deleting files over a certain size, and just re-archiving them. Just take account that there will already be questions where all files in a directory tree have been enumerated, those where all files based upon size have been isolated, and those where all files in a location have been archived, so your answer may just be three duplicates.

Comment: I have never seen the Where.exe what does that do?

Comment: Well you could start by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `where /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key to find out. However in the above code, it is essentially being used in a similar manner to the `dir` command. It is limited only to files, but it does have some peculiarities/features which, in this case, are useful. The main one being that unlike most other commands, it treats `.zip` as an exact extension, regardless of 8.3 naming, `dir` treats `.zip` as extensions beginning with `.zip`, so would pick up `.zipx` files too, for instance.